# Get url path to url links (PHP)

Tags: php, html, header, footer, geturl

For get img url I use this on main sites

```
<a href="./index.html"><img src="./images/logo.png" class="" alt=""></a>
```

But for sub sites I need to use this

```
<a href="../index.html"><img src="../images/logo.png" class="" alt=""></a>
```

How I can **get url** site using PHP code for this because I would like to create two PHP files, header and footer and I need something like get url site for url links and should work on both sites (main and sub).

I was trying to use

```
<img src="<?php echo url('images/logo.png') ?>" alt="">
```

but image not show.

Thanks

Comment: You can checkout the $_SERVER variables and either HTTP_HOST or PATH_INFO should help you out. http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your domain is www.example.com you might want to try getting the required information from the `REQUEST_URI that is $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

For example:

```
function get_image_path($image) {

    $parts = explode('/',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    $temp = array_shift($parts);
    $image_path = '';
    foreach($parts as $part){
        $image_path.='../';
    }
    return $image_path.$image;
}
```

Usage:

```
print get_image_path('images/1.jpg');
```

This should work for www.example.com/script.php and www.example.com/sub/script.php (and for any number of subfolders nested or not)

Use the same logic for your url($file) function

Comment: Yeap it's working for www.example.com great  :) but what about localhost? I'm using localhost as my test local server so your method not working here.